# Unable to create deployments/configmaps from kubectl client with Namespace Admin access in K8s

Tags: kubernetes

I gave namespace admin privilege to user 'X', he is unable to create deployments/configmaps from kubectl client. He is able to create them from K8s Dashboard(UI). Also he is not able to delete the deployments/configmaps from K8s Dashboard(UI),he need to use kubectl client for deleting deployments/configmaps.

The below snippets are the roles & Cluster roles which are binded to user 'X':

The below role states the user 'X' will have all the permissions within the namespace(ns):

```
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: Role
metadata:
  name: ns-admin-role
  namespace: ns  
rules:
- apiGroups:
  - '*'
  resources:
  - '*'
  verbs:
  - '*'
```

Created Role Binding using command line:

```
kubectl create rolebinding  {{usr}}-{{ns}}-admin-rolebinding --role=\"{{ns}}-admin-role\" --user={{usr}} --namespace=\"{{ns}}\"
```

In order to view the Dashboard UI.Some "Default Dashboard privileges of K8s v1.8" need to be set. Those have been setted like below:

```
kind: Role
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  namespace: kube-system
  name: user-role-dashboard
rules:
  - apiGroups: ["*"]
    resources:
      - services
    verbs: ["get", "list", "watch"]
  - apiGroups: ["*"]
    resources:
      - services/proxy
    verbs: ["get", "list", "watch", "create"]
```

Created Role Binding using command line:

```
kubectl create rolebinding  {{usr}}-dashboard-role-binding --role=\"user-role-dashboard\" --user={{usr}} --namespace=\"kube-system\"
```

The below snippet is for viewing the list of namespaces in the Dashboard UI:

```
kind: ClusterRole
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  name: ns-view-clusterrole
rules:
- apiGroups:
  - "*"
  resources:
  - namespaces
  verbs:
  - get
  - list
  - watch
```

Created Cluterrole Binding using command line:

```
kubectl create clusterrolebinding {{usr}}-ns-view-clusterrolebinding --clusterrole=\"ns-view-clusterrole\" --user={{usr}}
```

Is it K8s issue? or Did I miss anything?

Comment: Have you created the RoleBinding?

Comment: @NickRak -  yes I created

Comment: So could you add this yaml here?

Comment: @NickRak - Hey..! sorry I was in holiday. I updated the body with Clusterrolebinding & rolebindings. May I know whether you had reproduced the issue or not ?